# Why 'reservedConcurrency' isn't limiting the number of concurrent inflight messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-sqs, serverless

I am trying to limit the number of concurrent functions running in parallel. The trigger for my lambda is a message in a SQS Queue as you can see in my serverless.yml:

```
  receiver:
    handler: src/receiver.handler
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: ${queueArn}
          batchSize: 1   
    reservedConcurrency: 1
```

I used "reservedConcurrency: 1" to limit the number of concurrent executions to 1. I verified in the AWS UI the function 'receiver' configuration and the 'reserve concurrency' is also set to 1 there.

Not sure what I am missing since I am still seeing hundreds of executions being run from both my logs and the AWS SQS UI.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is your Lambda being triggered more than once *concurrently*? How many messages are being sent to SQS?

Comment: Yes, when I flood my queue with thousands of messages I can see hundreds of messages moving to the in-flight state. Since this could stress my system too much I would like to control the number of lambdas running concurrently at any point of time. Slowing down the consumption of the queue isn't an issue in my case.

Comment: After some research: https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0

Answer (score 4):

SQS/Lambda integration is not designed to work with reserved concurrency lower than 5.

> If you configure reserved concurrency on your function, set a minimum of 5 concurrent executions to reduce the chance of throttling errors when Lambda invokes your function.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

In-flight messages are not only those currently being processed by the Lambda function.  It also includes messages that are failing and going back to the queue due to insufficient concurrency being available on the Lambda function -- they will be in-flight while they are in the process of being attempted, even though most of the attempts will fail.  If you set your reserved concurrency to 0 you should find that all processing stops, but some number of messages remains in flight, because processing is still being attempted.

Comment: I see, so the 'reservedConcurrency' does not control the number of lambdas running but will throw a ThrottlingException if an SQS event triggers it while more than 'reservedConcurrency' are currently running. Which would lead this message to in-flight state and will retry in a later time. If this message fails again it will fall to my DLQ. Am I correct?
If I am, is there a way to control the number of message consume in the first place? Stopping the message to fall in the inflight state and actually wait for a lambda to be available before triggering the lambda?

Comment: Your synopsis seems correct.  The number 5 seems to be an artifact of the way AWS designed this service for fault tolerance and high performance -- the 5 messages are from 5 independent workers providedas a bridge between SQS and Lambda.  What you could do, of course, is increase the allowed deliveries in the queue's redrive policy so that messages are much less likely to end up in the DLQ.

Comment: After some more research: https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0

Answer (score -1):

Edouard linked to a medium article that explains more solutions to this issue (https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0).

But, I didn't find any of them particularly useful for my use case of limiting the non-configurable 5 queries for SQS messages the lambda integration uses.

My solution:

```
  processDatastoreHydrationMessages:
   handler: src/hydrateDatastores/processMessagesHandler.handler
   description: "Query SQS for a message and process it."
   memorySize: 440
   events:
     - schedule: rate(2 minutes)
```

Then, inside the handler:

```
const sqsClient = new SQS({ region: getRegion() });
const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: getRegion() });
console.log('Querying queue');
 
const response = await sqsClient
.receiveMessage({ QueueUrl: hydrationCommon.hydrationQueueUrl, MaxNumberOfMessages: 1, VisibilityTimeout: 900, WaitTimeSeconds: 0 })
.promise();

const [message] = response?.Messages || [];
console.log('received message');

if (!message || !message.ReceiptHandle) {
  return;
}

// //
// process message here
// //

console.log('Deleting message');

await sqsClient.deleteMessage({ QueueUrl: hydrationCommon.hydrationQueueUrl, ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle }).promise();

console.log('Finished processing messages');
```

The cron makes sure you are only ever having one Lambda run at once. This is kind of an anti-pattern as you are essentially slowing your system down. But, it can make sense for some types of report building or other intense data processing or ETL jobs.

Comment: [AWS documentation states that rules and schedules _could_ fire multiple times](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-troubleshooting.html#eb-rule-triggered-more-than-once). Therefore, you shouldn't rely on it to _make sure you are only ever having one Lambda run at once_.